# C# namespace vs directives

Tags: c#, namespaces, naming

I have years of experience in C++ and Java, but I am new to C#.

Recently when I was reading a book on C#, they address the following as name spaces, which I found it wierd. According to my knowledge in C++, these are actually `pre-processor directives`.

```
using System;                      //A book called these as namespace
using System.Collections.Generic;  //A book called these as namespace
using System.Text;                 //A book called these as namespace
```

And according to the msdn website, the above are known as `directives`.

If the above is call `namespace`

What about the following?

```
namespace My_First_Program  //This is also call namespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
    }
}
```

So **my first question is**: Which exactly is the namespace? Am I correct to call `using System;` as `pre-processor directive`?

**My second question is**: Can I assume`namespace My_First_Program` works similar to `using namespace std` in C++ ?

Comment: I think you need to see using as the same as import in java.

Comment: @StijnBernards That's what I thought, but I was later confused by the book's way of addressing it as a `namespace`.

Comment: They called it namespace because using actually uses a namespace.

Comment: `namespace My_First_Program{}` is a namespace definition and `using System;` imports the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The following statement defines the namespace:

```
namespace My_First_Program {
 ...
}
```

Any code within the braces is within the (wonderfully named) `My_First_Program` namespace.

The `using` statements 'import' namespaces so that you do not have to use their fully qualified name.

The 'using' statement is not a pre-processor directive. You can find a list of them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

No, C#'s [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) is not a [preprocessor directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx).

In C#, these are both almost identical to C++

```
using System;
```

would have similar intent to

```
using namespace std;
```

or in Java

```
import java.util.*;
```

viz that symbols in the `System` namespace are now in scope, provided that the requisite assemblies are also referenced by this project. Without `using`, all code which access `System` would need to qualify the full namespace as a prefix, e.g. `System.DateTime`. You can also alias a namespace with `using`, e.g. if the result of adding multiple `using` statements brings 2 or more symbols with the same name into scope, e.g. (`using m=My.Very.Long.NameSpace`)

Similarly:

```
namespace foo 
{

}
```

also has the same effect as it does in `C++` - this places all symbols defined in the block as in the namespace provided, `foo`. As with other languages, this is done to prevent cluttering the global namespace. This is quite similar to the `package` keyword in Java files. In theory in `C#` you can have multiple `namespace` blocks in a file, although this would be unusual and likely poor practice to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Using is the same as import in java.
Your book refered to it as namespace because using imports a namespace.

And yes to my knowledge using namespace std in c++ is the same as in c# using system;

Answer (score 0):

> Which exactly is the namespace? Am I correct
>   to call using System; as pre-processor directive?

No, `using System;` is just includes the namespace so you can access classes of `System` without specifying the *namescape*.this has nothing to do with [*preprocessor directives*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) in `C#`.

In this case, `System` is the namespace but before you include `System` namespace with a using directive, you have to add a reference to `System.dll`. `DLL` files are assemblies which can contain one or more namespaces.

> Can I assume namespace My_First_Program works similar to using namespace std in C++ ?

No,  `namespace My_First_Program` is [*declaration* of a namespace.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664763%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) `using namespace std` is similar to *using directive* in `C#`